# pylsp mypy plugin discarding result for a.py against b.py

Tags: python, mypy, language-server-protocol, pylsp

Sometimes pylsp returns an error result (over stderr?) withinformation such as `WARNING pylsp_mypy.plugin discarding result for a.py against b.py`

What does in mean? Should I, and can I, do something about it?